# How to bind textfields to attributes of one core data entity containing one row?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I have a view that wants to show summarized usage data for my app.  Conveniently enough I have a cocoa core data entity with all the usage data pre-aggregated (so it has only one row ever).  I would like to bind each individual attribute in the entity to different NSTextFields (eg not in an NSTableView).

This does not seem to be a usage pattern that core data + interface builder handles nicely.  So far what I am doing is duplicating my aggregated attributes into NSUserDefaults and binding my text fields to the defaults.  I would like an better, elegant way to do this.

Any better ideas out there?  Do I need to be smacked in the head with a big fat clue?

Thanks as always for reading...

Comment: Have you already looked at the Recipes core data sample program provided by Apple?

Comment: no I hadn't. I assume you mean [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html) -- will check it out

Comment: Now I have looked at it but no it does not scratch this particular itch.

Comment: Ah well, I thought I remembered seeing something like that in there.

Comment: The data binding example does what all the binding examples I have seen do - binds all the data to a table via a nsarraycontroller.  (and then fields get bound to the selected object in the array.)  So another way is having a hidden table on the dialog....hack hack hacky...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just hit my own head with my own big fat clue.
The solution was to use NSObjectController.

1. Add instance of NSObjectController to the NSWindowController implementation as an IBOutlet.
2. Add the NSObjectController to the xib for the dialog and bind the fields to it.
3. Link the NSObjectController in your view/window controller (File's Owner) to the NSObjectController in the xib.
4. Implement the controller's windowDidLoad.

In my case it looks like this in the header:

```
NSObjectController *dataCtrl;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSObjectController *dataCtrl;
```

And like this in the implementation

```
    @synthesize dataCtrl;
    ...
    - (void)windowDidLoad
    {
        NSManagedObject *totals = [StatsSupport getTotalRecord];
        [[self dataCtrl] setContent:totals];   // where the rubber meets the road
        [super windowDidLoad];
    }
```

And of course +[StatsSupport getTotalRecord] is your basic core data fetch type code which if you read this far you know how that looks. (and it will probably already exist since you need this code or something similar just to perform normal data reading/updating)

Lastly do a little happy dance because you made cocoa do some work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)updateFields {
  // fetch the row from the persistent store into your custom object
  // then get a reference to the data in your object, e.g.
  MyDataObject *data = [resultsArray objectAtIndex:0];

  myTextField1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [data.anIntegerValue intValue]];
  myTextField2.text = data.aTextValue; 
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: I guess by elegant I meant no code or nearly no code.  What I am doing now is about this much code (copying my data into user defaults). I am trying to fulfill the very-little-code potential of bindings.

Comment: In general, objective C is quite a "verbose" language. I sort of got used to it. I think this is intended, and it does make reading code easier.

Comment: Yes verbose indeed -- declare in class, "@property" + "@synthesize".  I am fine with that.  Interface Builder is a *usable* gui tool and I would like to leverage it as much as I can... hence this seemingly quixotic SO post.